# Question is modified after posting the correct answer

Tags: discussion

After answering a question correctly, the OP modified completely his question so that it has nothing to do with the original post. Is he allowed to do so?

Comment: No he is not. Flag a moderator for this problem.

Comment: No! That edit needs to be rolled back. Question edits *must not* invalidate existing valid answers.

Comment: Not sure how rollbacks work when you are below 2k. But if your attempt to rolling the edit back does not succeed, flag for moderator attention explaining the issue.

Comment: On a related note, see [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/334566).